# Changes to a Lotus Domino xpages java application do not propagate to the server

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Using Lotus Domino 8.5.2 Fixpack 3

The title sums it up. I have an xpages application that uses java. It seems that any java changes I make, never become visible on the server. It sounds a dead ringer for a cache issue of some kind. The application runs on the server and I see System.out.println statements in the server log, but do not any of the changes I've made to those statements or any new ones I've added.

The code is set to Rebuild Automatically. Still, it never looks like the server sees the changes. Is there some special way I need to build the database (aside from the typical Rebuild All)? Do I need to reset or restart some process on the domino server for it to see the changes?

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I'm returning to this project and, hence, this question. The specific error message I'm getting is:

```
 [6815810:00012-05659] 03/19/2013 09:27:01   HTTP JVM: Managedbean Calendar could not be created Can't instantiate class: 'calendar.CalendarServices'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calendar.CalendarServices. For more detailed inform
    ation, please consult error-log-0
    [6815810:00012-05659] 03/19/2013 09:27:01   HTTP JVM: xml located in /local/notesdata/domino/workspace/logs
    [6815810:00012-05659] 03/19/2013 09:27:01   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
```

I've tried unchecking automatic build and doing a clean --> rebuild all. I've tried signing the nsf again. I've ensured that I'm on the acl. And, as recommended, I've tried the

```
    restart task http
```

Command via live console. No matter what I do I'm getting this error. The odd thing is that this project is just a copy --> paste (with rename) of another one that works fine. So, the project works...until I change and recompile...

The log that exception above points to wasn't very helpful. It reads:

```
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2013-03-05T09:01:03.254-06:00" globalInstanceId="EL0a04a8b800013d3af27da200000008" msg="Managedbean Calendar could not be created Can&apos;t instantiate class: &apos;calendar.CalendarServices&apos;.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calendar.CalendarServices" severity="50" version="1.0.1">
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
        <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
            <values>SEVERE</values>
        </children>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
        <values>com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
        <values>createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
        <values>javax.faces.FacesException: Can&apos;t instantiate class: &apos;calendar.CalendarServices&apos;.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calendar.CalendarServices&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:234)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans(ApplicationAssociate.java:291)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:135)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:71)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveVariable(ServerSideLocalObject.java:97)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveAttribute(ServerSideLocalObject.java:73)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject._get(AbstractLocalObject.java:119)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject.getPropertyReference(AbstractLocalObject.java:101)&#xA;&#x9;at com</values>
        <values>.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findGlobalScopeIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:143)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:134)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIdentifier.interpret(ASTIdentifier.java:105)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:106)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTArgumentList.interpretArguments(ASTArgumentList.java:63)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:153)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)</values>
        <values>&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:220)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokePhaseMethodBinding(UIViewRootEx.java:1705)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.invokePhaseMethodBinding(FacesControllerImpl.java:444)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.access$0(FacesControllerImpl.java:438)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl$</values>
        <values>ViewPhaseListener.afterPhase(FacesControllerImpl.java:506)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:218)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:219)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:193)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:538)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1151)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServl</values>
        <values>et(ComponentModule.java:803)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:758)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:527)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1135)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:523)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:352)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:304)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:261)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:291)&#xA;Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calendar.CalendarServices&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController</values>
        <values>.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:255)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:216)&#xA;&#x9;... 51 more&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calendar.CalendarServices&#xA;&#x9;at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:194)&#xA;&#x9;at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:75)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory$1.run(ManagedBeanFactory.java:222)&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)&#xA;&#x9;... 52 more&#xA;</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="<server here>" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl" threadId="0" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
        <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
    </situation>
</CommonBaseEvent>
```

As ever, penny for your thoughts.

Also, thank you all for your feedback. I'm sorry I've been away for a bit and neglected this question. I really would like to figure this out.

Comment: Is it possible to get the server upgraded to the latest level (8.5.3 FP3) and then test if this has been fixed?

Comment: How about XPage changes?

Comment: I also turn off Rebuild Automatically. I hate to wait while it rebuilds every time I make a change AND if you multiple developers making changes in one database, design elements get built by the wrong IDs all the time.

Comment: Sometimes, when I make changes directly to a database, the changes will not appear in the Notes client until I restart my client. If I make the design changes in a template, then clean and build locally and refresh the design on the server, I have no caching problems at all.

Comment: Does console command "restart task http" any difference? If so, it should be something with cache. If not, your database is not built.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, no it doesn't make a difference. I came across several sites that, but it didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just silly. My src folder wasn't on the build path. That was causing all the issues.

Comment: Hmm..then it should not have worked at all after build. I've been having a lot of problems with an application on 8.5.2FP4 server where src folder keeps dropping from build path.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention *Project -> Clean* so try that first.

I had once similar problem that was caused by an underscore in class or package name.

If the problem exists also for XPages then it's a a general build problem. This can occur at least when developers with different Designer and/or ExtLib versions modify the application. When I had this problem the only way to fix it was to create a new application and copy paste everything there. In our case the other developer never had the problem.